# How do I store time using the Ebuka Rufus Onuchukwu code for saver app

Tags: android, filesaver.js

Does the code below detect external storage on android ?

```
private static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
            String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```